# Is there a built-in package management system in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, package-management, repository, windows-packagemanagement

Does Windows come with a package manager these days? I haven't used Windows in years. I'm hoping it has something similar to `yum`, `apt`, `pacman`, etc. found on various Linux distros. Obviously Windows isn't Linux, but it sounds like Windows and PowerShell etc. have come a long way.

I'd like to be able to automate the installation of a current version of Python for instance, from a batch script without all the monotonous GUI navigation. That kind of thing.

Comment: I am not aware of a package manager, but, since you can code, if you want to automate Windows, you simply can't beat the free Windwos scripting language [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) I have used it on & off for about 20 years now, and would reach to it for any scripting at all which is GUI based (Python for the rest of it).

Comment: I am not sure the reason this question was closed.  `PackageManagement` is a feature of Windows 10.  The question, "Does Windows come with a package manager these days?", has an answer that falls within scope here at Super User

Comment: Yes, there is [PackageManagement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-6). It's one of the tags so you can browse for related questions. I can post my answer on how to install python since the question was closed :(

Comment: `.MSI` is the closest thing to native support.  `PackageManagement` also exists on Windows 10 which supports `Chocolatey` packages.  `.MSI` support silent non-interactive mode by the way

Comment: In short, you'll need chocolatey so install it as a PackageProvider: `Install-PackageProvider chocolatey`. Then you can find the python package `Find-Package python` which shows it's provided by chocolatey. If you want python 2.7.x, the package name is `python2`. Install by `Install-Package python`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Windows 10 PowerShell has [PackageManagement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershell-6). For python, I believe you need to install [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) as a package provider first.

Here is how I was able to install python using PackageManagement.

1. Run PowerShell as administrator
2. `Install-PackageProvider chocolatey`

[image: Install chocolatey]

3. `Find-Package python`

[image: Find python]
This shows python 3.7.2, if you want python 2.7.x, use `python2`.

4. `Install-Package python`

[image: Install python]

Comment: When you install the `chocolatey` version, does it install to the default `%PATH%`, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across a **PowerShell** module called **OneGet** or **PackageMagement**.

You can do things like:

```
PowerShell GetPackageSource
PowerShell Find-Package Python3
PowerShell Install-Package Python3
```

You can bypass interaction and automate package download & installation like:

```
PowerShell Install-Package -Scope CurrentUser -Force Python3
```

I'm still figuring it out, not sure how well it works exactly, just yet.

Comment: FYI: This probably won't be the best answer, I don't know. I'm just putting it out there as I'm discovering it, in case it's useful to somebody.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Windows come with a package manager these days?

It's called `PackageManagement`.  It is a feature of the `Windows Management Framework 5.1` which (PowerShell 5.1) is installed by default on Windows 10.

`PackageManagement` supports `Chocolatey` packages.

[PackageManagement](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget)